# UNIX basic ftp upload

Tags: unix, terminal

I'm trying to get terminal to upload a file for me, in this case: file.txt
Unfortunately, it won't work, no matter what I try.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=*  
USER=*      
PASS=* 

# I'm 100% sure the host/user/pass are correct. 
#Terminal also connects with the host provided

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS

cd /Users/myname/Desktop

get file.txt #which is located on my desktop

bye
EOF
```

I've tried 100 different scripts but it just won't upload :(

This is the output after saving to an .sh file, chmod +x and sudo the .sh file:

```
Connected to *hostname*.
220 ProFTPD 1.3.4b Server ready.
331 Password required for *username*
230 User *username* logged in
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
550 /Users/myname/Desktop: No such file or directory
local: file.txt remote: file.txt
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||35098|)
550 file.txt: No such file or directory
221 Goodbye.
myname:Desktop Myname$
```

I've browsed through many other topics about the same issue here, but I just can't figure it out. I've started playing with UNIX since this morning, so excuse me for this (probably) foolish question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `put file.txt` instead of `get file.txt` because you want to upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST=*  
USER=*      
PASS=* 

# I'm 100% sure the host/user/pass are correct. 
#Terminal also connects with the host provided

cd /Users/myname/Desktop # Go the the local folder where the file is located in

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS

cd /User/$USER/Desktop # Go to the folder in which you want to upload the file

put file.txt #which is located on my desktop

bye
EOF
```

So use put and make sure your file is the current working directory and the remote directory exists.

Comment: Omg indeed. I re-read the script a couple of times... I knew I had to use put, but I just didn't see I was using put X_X Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `get` but talk about an *upload*.  Probably you just want to use `put`?

Anyway, I'm not sure this can be done using a basic `ftp` client.  I'm always using `ncftp` for things like this.  This comes with command line utilities like `ncftpput` which accept command line arguments and options to perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

Alfe is right, you need to use `put <filename>` to upload a file to FTP. You can find a quick guide [here](http://dwardmac.pitzer.edu/classes/skills/ftp/unixftp.html). It should be possible using the basic FTP tool but I would also recommend ncftp :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `put` to upload a file.